# How to implement a button onto a button, to delete the parent and the child with the same click, without having the parent be clickable? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a dynamically loaded List that consists of different buttons. If a button is clicked, the corresponding entry of the list will be destroyed. Now I want to have a child button on each of the dynamically created parent buttons, that will destroy the parent and the child. And the parent should "lose" this delete function.

```
public void AddMoreButton()
{
    if (lectureInput.text.Length < 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    lectureTitle.text = lectureInput.text;
    creditsTitle.text = creditsInput.text;
    swsTitle.text = swsInput.text;
    GameObject button = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabButton);
    Button buttonInstance = button.GetComponentInChildren<Button>();
    buttonInstance.onClick.AddListener(() => { Destroy(button); });
    button.transform.SetParent(panel.transform, false);
    button.layer = 5;
    button.SetActive(true);
    ClearInputs();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pretty much copy paste the button creation code, and just move `Destroy(button)` into its `AddListener` call. Make sure you don't change the parent button when creating the `childButton` except for in the `Destroy(button)` call. You can set the parent to the button, too:

```
public void AddMoreButton()
{
    if (lectureInput.text.Length < 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    lectureTitle.text = lectureInput.text;
    creditsTitle.text = creditsInput.text;
    swsTitle.text = swsInput.text;
    GameObject button = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabButton);
    Button buttonInstance = button.GetComponentInChildren<Button>();
    childButtonInstance.onClick.AddListener(() => { /*whatever the parent button should do*/ });
    button.transform.SetParent(panel.transform, false);
    button.layer = 5;
    button.SetActive(true);

    GameObject childButton = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabButton);
    Button childButtonInstance = childButton.GetComponentInChildren<Button>();
    buttonInstance.onClick.AddListener(() => { Destroy(button); });
    childButton.transform.SetParent(button, false);
    childButton.layer = 5;
    childButton.SetActive(true);

    ClearInputs();
}
```

You'll probably have to adjust its position with `childButton.transform.Translate(Vector3(0f,0.5f,0f));` or something so that it doesn't overlap with its parent button.

Comment: It worked. However, I had to change buttonInstance.onClick... to childButtonInstance.onClick... in the lower section of the code.